# Jquery .post method is sending a null value. How to pass actual value to controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that applies to an edit view in asp.net MVC. I have an actionlink that sends the row Id to the controller which then brings back the correct row to see in the associated view.

I then have a partial view below that. That also requires a parameter in order to bring associated data from another table.

I have a Jquery .post call that runs after the page is loaded. I can alert out and show the exact value I want to send to the controller.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = "/Home/MmsAndNotes";
        var Uc = $("#Id").serialize();
        alert(Uc);
        $.post(url, {Id: Uc}, function (data) {
          alert("what is Uc now? " + uc); //just for testing
        });
    })
```

I have also used it this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = "/Home/MmsAndNotes";
        var Uc = $("#Id").val();
        alert(Uc);
        $.post(url, Uc, function (data) {

        });
    })
```

the alerts come up and show the value I want. However, when the .post call runs, it sends a null value. Here is my controller.

```
 public ActionResult MmsAndNotes(string Id)
    {
        //Declare LogisticsVM for individual policy info
        LogisticsMMS_NotesVM model;
        if(uc == null)
        {
            return Content("uc is empty.");
        }

        int val = Convert.ToInt32(uc);

        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            LogisticsMMS_NotesDTO dto = db.LogisticsMMS.Find(val);

            //confirm policy exists
            if (dto == null)
            {
                return Content("This policy cannot be found." + val);
            }

            model = new LogisticsMMS_NotesVM(dto);
        }

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

It always returns as uc is empty. I repeat, when the alerts come up. I get the correct value to send to the controller. But once it sends, something happens and it converts to null. HELPPPPP.. please .. I'm losing my mind over this one.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result.. I had tried that one as well.

Comment: What if you do `$.post(url, {uc: "Test string"}, ...)` - do you get anything?

Comment: Nope.. it still sends as null. I have this as a little test.  if(uc == "Test String")
            {
                return Content("uc is Test string.");
            }   This is in the controller

Comment: Why not just use break points instead of writing code-based tests? Case in point, my example had "Test string" but you're testing for "Test String", which are not equal due to case sensitivity. Not sure that matters but just a note. Also - what is `$("#Id")`? A `<form>`?

Comment: You're right. Break points is a much better idea. I'm terrible at using them and can't really see what I'm looking for that way. So, the code based on this works okay. I capitalized the Test String in the check. I even shortened it "Test"  It still comes back null.

Comment: P.S $("#Id") comes from this   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) .. the alerts I have in the Jquery pull the correct value out and display it for me.

Comment: I figured it out. I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but changing my $.post() call to an $.ajax({}) call solved the issue. As you can see above, I had the $.post call. Using this instead,

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/MmsAndNotes",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { Id: Uc }
        });
```

Solved it. I thought Jquery's shortened calls worked the same way. They certainly might, but doing it this way was the only way it worked for me.

P.S. Thanks Tyler (above) for your comments.

Answer (score -1):

this solution should be work  :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/MmsAndNotes',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "html",

        data: { uc : $("#Id").val() }, 
     success: function (result) { 
         code here
                               }
    });
        })
```

**You need to verify if $("#Id").val() is not empty**

Comment: If the value were empty, the result wouldn't be `null`, but an empty string.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: If `.val()` were empty, it would be set to `""` (an empty string). `""` and `null` are not the same. OP's code confirms that the value is `null`.